# Connecting to socket.io on production server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm testing my socket.io on Node.js server using postman and react client.
I tried the following with postman:

> https://example.com/api/socket.io/?uuid=xyz

> https://example.com/api/?uuid=xyz

> https://example.com/?uuid=xyz

But I'm always getting this error on postman:

> Status Code: 404 Not Found

I'm also testing it on my client (locally) using this url:

```
https://example.com/api/
```

I'm using NginX on my server. The config file for NginX is the following:

```
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name example.com;

        # reverse proxy
        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;

                proxy_http_version                 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

                # Proxy headers
                proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host              $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And I'm getting this error in Chrome:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://example.com/socket.io/?role=admin&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OtWg0Ap'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. socket__io-client.js?v=14998397:898

> GET https://example.com/socket.io/?role=admin&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OtWg0Ap
> net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)

I changed the real address for obvious reasons.

I need socket.io on the server to be able to connect to the client and other devices outside of the server as well. That's why you see the client as "role=admin" and "uuid=xyz" in the query.

This is my Node.js server code:

```
require('dotenv').config('.env');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const errorController = require('./middlewares/errorController');
const connectDB = require('./db');
const { deviceWebSocket } = require('./controllers/device.websocket');


const PORT = process.env.PORT;
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

////////////////// CONNECT DATABASE /////////////////////
connectDB();

// Set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

////////////////// INIT MIDDLEWARES ////////////////////
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
// to be able to send JSON from postman without form-data
app.use(express.json());
// Development logging
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
    max: 100,
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!'
  });
app.use('/api', limiter);

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());


const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket(server,{
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
// global is used to make io available throughout the entire project
global.io = io;

io.on('connection', socket => { deviceWebSocket(socket) });

//////////////////////// Routes ////////////////////////
app.use('/api/v1/admins', require('./controllers/admin.controller'));
app.use(`/api/v1/devices`, require('./controllers/device.controller'));
app.use(`/api/v1/layouts`, require('./controllers/layout.controller'));
app.use(`/api/v1/playlists`, require('./controllers/playlist.controller'));
app.use(`/api/v1/media`, require('./controllers/media.controller'));
///////////////////// 404 NOT FOUND ERROR ///////////////////////
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(404).send({
        message: `Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`,
        success: false
    });
});

///////////////////////// ERROR MIDDLEWARE //////////////////////
app.use(errorController);


server.listen(PORT, () => {
    // console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
    console.info(`server started in ${PORT}`);
});
```

Everything works perfectly on my local machine. But not in production.

Thanks in advance...